# Method Trigger in Kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the dummy data in the following jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/epvg86qu/18/ and when user clicks on the line, then it calls `DetailChart_Click()` method draws other data series `(stats,stats2)`, viceversa.

However when I try to implement this functionality (`seriesClick`) in my actual project, it only calls `DetailChart_Click()` method once when it initialize.However, it does not call/trigger that method when user clicks on the line series.

```
var isHover=false;  

self.updateChart = function () {
            var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
            chart.options.series = self.dataSeries1;                          
            chart.options.seriesClick = DetailChart_Click();        
            chart.refresh();
 }

function DetailChart_Click() {
        console.log("hello");
        if (!isHover) {
            var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
            chart.options.series = self.dataSeries2;
            chart.redraw();
            isHover = true;
        }
        else if (isHover) {
            var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
            chart.options.series = self.dataSeries1;
            chart.redraw();
            isHover = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your fiddle works as expected, it uses `DetailChart_Click` instead of `DetailChart_Click()` because it's referencing the function, not running it.

Comment: @JKirchartz, How should I make it work? Should I make it             `chart.options.seriesClick=DetailChart_Click` ?

Comment: I think that would work (note: I've never used kendoCharts)

Comment: I tried that as well, it did not work. By doing that, it does not event call DetailChart_Click() at once.

Comment: Have you bound the `click` event to your function? It ran once during initialization because you called it when assigning `chart.options.seriesClick = DetailChart_Click();` (function name followed by a parentheses `()` is a function call)

Comment: Check my answer. Added some explanation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below snippet to bind your `DetailChart_Click()` after initialization:

```
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
chart.bind("seriesClick", DetailChart_Click);
```

Taken from [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#events-seriesClick).

Alternatively, bind it during initialization as shown in their [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/events).

**Additional note**

What you are doing currently below:

```
chart.options.seriesClick = DetailChart_Click();
```

is *calling* the `DetailChart_Click` function and assign the *return value* (which is `undefined` as it has no return value) to `seriesClick`, which is not what you want. Generally if you want to register *callbacks* such as this one, you'd want to omit those parentheses (which makes it a reference to the function `DetailChart_Click`) and assign it to the `seriesClick`, which is what you intended to do.

However, even if you remove the parentheses in your code above, you assigned it wrongly, as the `seriesClick` callback should be registered by `bind` method of the `chart`, instead of assigning it to the `options` property of the `chart`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: do you have any idea of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281700/chart-area-and-legend-area-automatically-updates