# Chart Area and Legend Area automatically updates

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a chart and implemented `seriesClick` event. When User clicks it loads `dataA`, when user click again it loads `dataB`. It is fully implemented and it is functional. However my question is how to fix chart area and legend area.

Legend length differs in `dataA` and `dataB`, therefore when user click on series, chart is not stay stable, it adjusts automatically. I do not want my chart to adjust automatically.

[image: first dataset]

[image: second dataset]

my SeriesClick event implementation is as follows:

```
     function clickEvent (e) {
             if (!isHover) {
                 chart.options.series = dataSeries2;
                 chart.redraw();
                 isHover = true;
             }
             else if (isHover) {
                 var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
                 chart.options.series = dataSeries;
                 chart.redraw();
                 isHover = false;
             }
         }
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/72/

Comment: This question still feels rather unclear to me. What adjusts? Is it the scales of x- and/or y-axis? Or the size of the whole chart? Is it possible to provide a JSFiddle/screenshot?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/72/

Comment: I have added screenshot and jsfiddle. Please see updated question

Comment: Simplest solution would be to put the legend at the bottom:  http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/73/

Comment: Thanks a lot Ezanker, however requirement says legends should be on the right hand side(default) to chart, not bottom.

Comment: You want the legend text to word-wrap?

Comment: is that the only option? I am asking because legend itself has some functionalities like when user clicks it hides and unhides, but text does not have this fucnctionalities

Comment: I want the x-y area/legend area to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API yet for setting plot area to have fixed width, all you can do right now is give an escape character (\n) in your legend label.

```
stats = stats.map(function(x) {
    return { x: x[0], y: x[1], k: x[2],name:"my title\nis too\nlengty" };
});
```

I found [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/fix-plotarea-width-of-chart) in their forum, hope that will help you out.